# GroupBy in pandas and create new columns from values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
a b
A 1
A 2
B 5
B 5
B 4
C 6
C 7
C 8
C 9
```

I would like to group by column `a` and put the values of column `b` to separate columns. Obviously I will need padding and/or clipping of the number of values, let's say if I choose 3 as max length of values and zero padding, I'd like to have the resulting dataframe like this:

```
a b_0 b_1 b_2
A  1   2   0
B  5   5   4
C  6   7   8
```

How can I achieve this with pandas / numpy?

Comment: you can use: `df.set_index(['a',df.groupby('a').cumcount()])['b'].unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('b_').reset_index()`

Comment: thank you for redirecting me to the pivot kb article

Comment: No problem:) ...